# Changing product prices based on the current currency

Tags: product, currency, price, multicurrency

The client doesn't want to create 2 websites for 2 base currencies. But they want the prices of the alternative currency to be rounded to 0.5 or 0.9. The pre-calculated prices should be shown on listings, product pages, cart page etc.

Example: 
Price in base currency: 5 GBP. In EUR it would be ~6.31 but should be shown as 6.5.

Is this possible at all?

Magento version is 1.9. The currencies are GBP (base) and EUR.

Answer (score 1):

If you use 2 websites, you can set the price scope to 'website' from System->Configuration and then you should be able to set a different base currency for each website. So you can enter the price differently for each website.  You can have on 5GBP on one website and 6.5 EUR on the other website.