# Using multiple websites on single domain?

Tags: magento-1.9, currency, websites, multicurrency

Is it possible to use 2 websites on single domain? If so, what are the consequences?

Here is my main problem: [Changing product prices based on the current currency](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45603/changing-product-prices-based-on-the-current-currency) Please take a look.

I've red everything that I found on the net about this but couldn't find any solution. I tried to explain that this is not possible but the Client still wants this functionality...

So it seems the only solution is to create a second website with another base currency. I will not use different domains, product descriptions and images, themes, stores etc. The only thing which I will use are the different prices. I've never worked on multi-site environment so I'm not sure what's going on at all. Probably I have to change the website after selecting a currency from the currency selector.

But I'm still not sure what happens with the orders, customers etc. Are they different for each website? If so, this is not good at all. Also what happens if the customer have items in the basket and changes the website (from the currency selector)? Is the basket get lost for the other website? Is it possible to share sessions and so on between the websites (and not just stores)?

The multi-site tutorials which I found are for multi-domain environments so I'm not even sure whether it is possible to use multiple websites on single domain.

Is it worth managing 2 websites just for this price rounding? I tried telling the Client to skip this functionality but maybe I can't explain why it doesn't worth. I think that they are thinking like "it should be easy to do" and I can't explain why it is not. Any directions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple websites under the same domain and have a unified shopping cart and the same customer account for all websites. Only if the websites are on separate domains this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple website / Store via

```
Magento admin > System > Managestore and create website / store / storeview
```

If you need same categories for two store you can use default category on root category. After that you need to create folder in your magento folder as second website/store in that copy the `index.php` and `.htaccess` file from your magento files and paste it in to new folder as you created.

Then go to `Admin panel > system > configuration > in the left` switch to your second store view then go to web change base url.